# Changes in Instant.now() between java 11 and java 17 in AWS Ubuntu standard 6.0

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, java-11, java-17

We are moving to Java 17 (correto17) from Java 11 (correto11). As part of this, we also have to upgrade Ubuntu to `standard:6.0` from `standard:4.0` in AWS as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html).

We are observing that in Java 11 and Java 17 `Instant.now()` output is a bit different.

For example,

```
System.out.println("Instant: " + Instant.now());
```

is giving output like below

- Java 11 - `Instant: 2022-12-12T18:04:27.267229Z`
- Java 17 - `Instant: 2022-12-12T18:04:27.267229114Z`

Can someone let me know what is causing this? How can I make the behaviour same in both the cases?

Comment: Related: https://twitter.com/indyarni/status/1484193762788184068

Comment: Hasn't Instant always had a precision of nanoseconds? I would expect the difference to be that `Instant.now()` can now return a value which has a non-zero "submicrosecond" part.

Comment: In my local Mac (Ventura 13.0.1) `OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.5+0)` and `openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18` I am not observing this change. It is returning the value same as in Java 11. Not sure if it is something specific to `correta17`.

Comment: The format printed is documented and unchanged from Java 11 to Java 17. You need to follow links a couple of steps from [`Instant.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#toString()) to find it. What is different in your two cases is the value you are printing. The former has zeroes in the last places, which is why they are not printed.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes that I understood. In `corretojava17` there are no extra zeroes and this behaviour is not same across all flavors of OpenJDK 17. For example, `OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.5+0)` and `openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18` is also having zeroes in the last place like the way it was in JDK 11.

Comment: On my OpenJDK 18 I get groups of three decimals, for example `2022-12-13T15:13:13.100Z`, or `2022-12-13T15:13:13.000000100Z`, which I didn’t readily see documented, but may also not be in direct conflict with the documentation, which just states of the fraction of second: *As many digits will be output as required.* Is this what you are seeing too? And what would your desired output be instead?

Comment: For consistent output use a formatter, for example `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(Instant.now())`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Instant#now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now()) obtains the current instant from the system clock. If the system clock returns a precision of only up to microseconds, the `Instant#toString` simply truncates the last three zeros from the nine digits. If the system on which you are running Java 17 (correto17) returns a precision of nanoseconds, you can truncate it to the precision of microseconds using [`Instant#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        Instant truncatedToMicros = instant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MICROS);
        System.out.println(truncatedToMicros);
    }
}
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Is this change specific to correto17? In my local Mac `OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.5+0)` and `openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18` I am not observing this change. It is returning the value same as in Java 11.

Comment: This will usually output 6 decimals, for example `2022-12-13T15:19:03.686502Z`. Note that if the truncated value happens to fall on a whole millisecond or coarser, fewer digits will be output, for example `2022-12-13T15:20:00Z` (observed on OpenJDK 18).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and what we need to notice is that when we use MacOS, the time API will just works as 6 digs precision, but when we use Linux(such as Ubuntu), it will be 9 digs : )

Comment: If you are simply adding something to another answer, put it as a comment